# How to complete remove all links to default PHP version?

Tags: homebrew, apache, php

Running macOS Sierra.

How can I complete remove all links to the default installed PHP version? I have installed PHP 7 through homebrew but when I run scripts that call external CLI applications programatically they still seem to end up using PHP 5.6.25 which is the default installed PHP version.

What can I do to break all ties to this PHP version?

My `php -v` and `phpinfo()` already show the proper PHP7 version that I installed. Somehow some scripts still try to look for the default version.

I already read you cannot simply delete it.

If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5
sudo ln -s `which php` /usr/bin/php
```

The first command backs up the old PHP binary. It can still be used by invoking `php5` in a command line. The second command symlinks the new PHP 7 binary to the location of the old PHP binary. Therefore, scripts that use the old location will start using the new PHP version.